# Export HTML Table to Excel- Doesn't Open in Office 2010

Tags: javascript, excel

I am using the following Javascript code to generate an excel on the fly, which converts HTML table to a spreadsheet.

The excel file does not open in Office 2010, shows blank. The same spreadsheet opens with Openoffice. What can be the issue? Is this something related to `encoding`

```
function ExcelReport() {
              var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
              tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';
              tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Test Sheet</x:Name>';
              tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
              tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';      
              tab_text = tab_text + "<table>";
              var headingTable = $('#h_tbl').clone();
              tab_text = tab_text + headingTable.html();
              tab_text = tab_text + '</table>';
              $('.c_tbl').each(function( index ) {
                    tab_text = tab_text + "<table>";
                    tab_text = tab_text + "<tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>";
                    tab_text = tab_text + '</table>';
                    tab_text = tab_text + "<table>";
                    var exportTable = $(this).clone();
                    tab_text = tab_text + exportTable.html();
                    tab_text = tab_text + '</table>';
              });
              tab_text = tab_text + '</body></html>';
              var fileName = name + '.xls';
              var blob = new Blob([tab_text], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8" })
              window.saveAs(blob, wo_var + ".xls");
            }
```

When I open the excel in notepad the html code looks like the following

```
<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>
        <tbody><tr><td>abc:</td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>
```

[image]

Comment: Is this without any error messages? Try View-Window-Unhide, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Hide-or-show-worksheets-or-workbooks-69f2701a-21f5-4186-87d7-341a8cf53344#bmhideworkbookwindow

Comment: @AxelRichter Yes without any error message, I updated the question with the HTML of the excel

Answer (score 43, accepted):

We had the same issue too many complaints from our customers.  We traced it to the  Excel OFffice Security patch KB3115262 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3115262  Which came out July 12, 2016

To work around the issue, we had customers make a change in their Excel to allow files from the internet.

To fix:
1) Open Excel Go to File Options

2) Click Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings

3) Go to Protected View.  there are 3 options that show that were all clicked

We uncheck the first option that reads -- "Enable Protected View for files originating from the Internet"

That fixed the issue.  Perhaps not the best solution.  I'm not sure why this particular KB broke this but I think perhaps the fact the file format is not expected and this setting are conflicting with each other.

On a computer I have that doesn't have this KB installed, all those are checked and it still works fine (not blank but prompts file format is different) and I think shows in protected view.

What led us to fact its not the content of the file is we noticed if we resave the file in notepad or notepad++ without making any changes, the file behaves fine so excel must be reading some property of the file rather than the content to block it.

Comment: Thanks, spent an hour trying to find why it suddenly stopped working

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot.

For german office users:
Datei -> Optionen -> Trust Center -> Einstellungen für das Trust Center -> Geschützte Ansicht -> Haken entfernen bei "Geschützte Ansicht bei Dateien aus dem Internet aktivieren"

Comment: Several customer emails and a couple hours of work in, and I find this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You are saving a file with HTML content as `*.xls`. Excel can open this but will normaly show a warning message:

> The file you are trying to open, 'name.ext', is in a different format
>   than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not
>   corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you
>   want to open the file now?

If that warning not occurs and the file is not opening, then maybe the

`DWORD` Value `ExtensionHardening` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version number>\Excel\Security` is set to `2` in `Windows Registry`

That means "Check the file name extension and the file type. If they do not match, do not open the file."

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/948615.

Maybe your administrator has set this via Group Policy setting. If you are in an administrated network, ask your administrator.

If you are administrator of your own, then look for that registry setting and change it to `1`, the default.

Comment: How do I get rid of the warning message?

Comment: Have you read the linked knowledge base site? To get rid of the warning message set DWORD ExtensionHardening to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing:

> We uncheck the first option that reads -- "Enable Protected View for files originating from the Internet" which is not safe

Do this:

> Go to Properties of the file and click Unblock (If you know the file is safe).

Image: [Go to Properties of the file and click Unblock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtK52.png)

Comment: This works. And it offers a file-to-file option hence better security than the global setting.

Comment: i do not installed office, i open my docs in either google docs or one drive :| and they generate error, doesn't matter if the output format is HTML, or Base64

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, intranet wise.  Grid export to HTML Excel all of a sudden stopped working when user clicked the open.  Quick workaround, Save and Open drop down option or just save then open.

My fix was to change content-disposition from attached to inline.  Now the users get the old popup center page instead of the one at the bottom and open works just fine.

Comment: This should be the top answer, worked perfectly, didn't require asking anyone to change any trust settings. No way those trust settings are going to get changed in a corporate environment.

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue, my code dumps from a GridView to an XLS file using StringWriter, HTMLTextWriter and RenderControl.

Since our ASP.NET code runs on a company intranet we uninstalled the following updates across the company instead of going into 100s of user PCs and changing their settings.

Uninstalled:

- Windows Update KB3115262 (Excel 2013)
- Windows Update KB3115130 (Excel 2010)
- Windows Update KB3115272 (Excel 2016/64 bit)

This fixed our issue, and would also fix yours and others affected by these updates.

Answer (score 1):

For those more security paranoid, I saw another answer on SalesForce site, which should work too - https://success.salesforce.com/answers#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=All&criteria=BESTANSWERS&id=9063A000000iTIyQAM

Basically marking the site you are downloading from as safe.

I haven't tried it myself

Basically open the website where you will be downloading excel files in Internet Explorer

Go to Settings
Internet Options
Security
Trusted Sites
Sites
Add

This should add the site in question as allowed and then you can use whatever browser you want e.g. firefox / chrome etc.

Answer (score 1):

Possible fixes for the problem:

**Solution 1:**

1) Type Regedit in start menu

2) Navigate to registry as,

In the registry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\\Excel\Security

where  =

```
 15.0 for Office 2013
 16.0 for Office 2016
 12.0 for Office 2010
```

create a DWORD(32bit) value and name it: ExtensionHardening.
The possible values are:

```
0: Do not check the file name extension and
   the file type, and bypass the function of the warning message.

1: Check the file name extension and the file type.
   If they do not match, display the warning message.

2: Check the file name extension and the file
   type. If they do not match, do not open the file.
```

Use 1 as the value.

**Solution 2:**

Right click on Excel -->Properties-->Unblock-->Ok.

[UnblockExcel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kNIH.png)

**SOlution 3**

**Uninstall the updates:**

Windows Update KB3115272 (Excel 2016/64 bit)

Windows Update KB3115262 (Excel 2013)

Windows Update KB3115130 (Excel 2010)

For more info about the issue .please refer the link below.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2d84793-9920-45e3-baef-5027a4ac1ae0/kb3170008-for-office-2016-breaks-functionality-ms16088?forum=officeitpro

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft patched Excel on Aug 9 to restore the original functionality. Scroll to post on Aug 9 in this thread for more info: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2d84793-9920-45e3-baef-5027a4ac1ae0/kb3170008-for-office-2016-breaks-functionality-ms16088?forum=officeitpro

Updating Excel fixed the problem for me.