# Response.ContentType application/vnd.ms-excel xls stopped working

Tags: html, excel, xls

I've done some pretty deep searching on this issue with no luck.  It seems that in the past couple of days the output to XLS from HTML has stopped working on many legacy (read: Classic ASP) systems I support.  I've been able reproduce this on multiple servers, multiple independent source code from Office 2010 through Office 2016.  I've looked at everything I can think of without success so I'm curious to know if there is something I might be overlooking.  I'm starting to think this may be a bad Office update that is the culprit.

Sample of what works and has been working for many years:

```
<%

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=TestExcel.xls"

%>

<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>column 1 header</th>
                    <th>column 2 header</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>column 1 value</td>
                    <td>column 2 value</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td>Footer 1</td>
                    <td>Footer 2</td>

                </tr>

            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is curious is that the XLS file is in fact created but when it is opened Excel opens but not file is present.

Even more curious is that when you open the XLS file with some text editor (notepad for example) and just File->Save As it opens without issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is related to Microsoft Security Update KB3115262 for Excel that was released July 12, 2016. The security update information can be found in Microsoft Security Bulletin MS16-088 - Critical.

I've found three workarounds (in my order of preference):

- Instead of clicking Open, save the file and then open it
- In Excel Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Protected View, uncheck the top two options. This is potentially unsafe.
- Uninstall the security update.

Below are several links regarding the issue for further perusal. 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2d84793-9920-45e3-baef-5027a4ac1ae0/kb3170008-for-office-2016-breaks-functionality-ms16088?forum=officeitpro

https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS16-088

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131404/end-user-cannot-open-a-xls-report-exported-from-salesforce

[Export HTML Table to Excel- Doesn't Open in Office 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377796/export-html-table-to-excel-doesnt-open-in-office-2010)

Comment: Bingo!  That's the issue.  I was already planning a fun filled night of rolling back updates to find which one was the culprit. ;)  I think the least path of resistance is the Trust Center option since it will likely be at least days before MS fixes.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: great - option 2 worked for me, unchecking the first option (internet files)

Comment: MS patch to fix this issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3181507

Comment: Unchecking only the "Enable Protected View for files originating from the Internet" checkbox in Excel Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Protected View worked for me.  On a hunch, I tried checking that box and then adding the download site to my list of Trusted Sites in Windows 10 Internet Options > Security > Trusted Sites > Sites and that enabled me to download and open the Excel Workbook via my MS Edge browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go to properties of the file and click Unblock.

I think is safer than change the Excel Trust Center

Comment: I'm definitely not a fan of the security risk but the problem is this method is used on literally hundreds of web reports for hundreds of users.  The volume of affected systems/users is too high to manage the support from the users unfortunately.  Here's to fingers crossed that MS will address it this decade. :)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 users, add the Excel download site URL to your list of Trusted Sites in Windows 10 Internet Options > Security > Trusted Sites > Sites then download and open the Excel Workbook via your MS Edge browser.