# Xls Export in not running on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, xls

```
 public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
    {   
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = db.Details.Select(x => new
        {
            x.Title,
            Category = x.Category.Title,
            SubCategory = x.SubCategory.Title,
            x.Count,
            x.Price,
            Automobiles = x.Automobiles.Count,
            x.Description
        }).ToList();
        gv.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;            
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Marklist.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gv.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
        return Json(true);
    }
```

Export works well locally . It does not work on Azure. Downloading an empty file . Tell me what's the problem ?

Comment: Is this using COM by any chance?

Comment: Also do you need to have Excel installed for this to work locally?

Comment: @evilSnobu No, that clearly does not use COM or Excel Interop.

Comment: Have you debugged it on the server? Verified that you've actually retrieved data from the database? Why are you generating HTML files and serving them up with an XLS extension? That's a poor practice and Microsoft has issued an update that makes that almost unsuable. Why are you returning JSON from your method and ending the response instead of returning a file result? Why are you using a GridView in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue might be related to the recent Microsoft Security Update for Excel.

See... https://stackoverflow.com/a/38467132/6610346