# Exporting HTML table to Excel using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am exporting `HTML` table to `xls` foramt. After exporting if you open it in Libre Office, it works fine but the same opens a blank screen in Microsoft Office.

I don't want a `jquery` solution please provide any `javascript` solution.
Please help.

```js
function fnExcelReport() {
    var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
    var textRange;
    var j = 0;
    tab = document.getElementById('table'); // id of table

    for (j = 0; j < tab.rows.length; j++) {
        tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
        //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, ""); //remove if u want links in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); // remove if u want images in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer
    {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus();
        sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
    } else //other browser not tested on IE 11
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));

    return (sa);
}
```

```html
<iframe id="txtArea1" style="display:none"></iframe>

    Call this function on

        <button id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport();"> EXPORT 
        </button>

    <table id="table">
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head1</th>
            <th>Head2</th>
            <th>Head3</th>
            <th>Head4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>31</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>34</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>44</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: have you tried to open a real html with `<html><head>...<body>...` in Excel, not just a `<table>`? or saving as `csv`?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377796/export-html-table-to-excel-doesnt-open-in-office-2010

Comment: @Aprillion I tried with CSV but I don't want CSV as the extension.

Comment: @AxelRichter I cant say user to follow those steps from settings to get the result.

Comment: @Srinivas Pai: Surely you can't. So stop exporting `HTML` as a fake `*.xls`. [Datatables](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html) exitsts.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On 2016-07-12, Microsoft pushed a [security update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3170008) for Microsoft Office. One of the effects of this update was to prevent HTML files from non-trusted domains from being opened by Excel, because they cannot be opened in Protected mode.

There is ALSO a registry setting that prevents Excel from opening files with the .XLS file extension whose contents do not match the official XLS file format, though it defaults to 'warn', not 'deny'.

Prior to this change, it was possible to save HTML data to a file with an XLS extension, and Excel would open it correctly - possibly [giving a warning first](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/948615) that the file did not match the Excel format, depending on the user's value for the `ExtensionHardening` registry key (or related config values).

Microsoft has [made a knowledge-base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3181507) entry about the new behavior with some suggested workarounds.

Several web applications that previously relied on exporting HTML files as XLS have run into trouble as a result of the update - [SalesForce](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iTIyQAM) is one example.

Answers from before July 12th 2016 to this and similar questions are likely to now be invalid.

It's worth noting that files produced ON THE BROWSER from remote data do not fall afoul of this protection; it only impedes files downloaded from a remote source that is not trusted. Therefore one possible approach is to generate the .XLS-labelled HTML file locally on the client.

Another, of course, is to produce a valid XLS file, which Excel will then open in Protected mode.

**UPDATE**: Microsoft has released a patch to correct this behavior: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3181507

Comment: Not to hijack this answer, but I figured it would be worth mentioning. Excel can open .CSV and .TSV files, both of which are very simple to create in Javascript. I haven't seen any specific documentation saying they've changed this behavior; maybe this is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 12):

[SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) seems perfect for this.

To export your table as an excel file use the code in this [link](http://sheetjs.com/demos/Export2Excel.js)(along with SheetJS)

Just plug in your `table` element's id into `export_table_to_excel`

See [Demo](http://sheetjs.com/demos/table.html)

Comment: Looks like it hasn't been updated in a while - is it up to date? (I don't actually know of any changes to the format that would cause it not to be, but it's the first question I'm going to get if I suggest it...)

Comment: I don't think the format has changed, and the only warning Excel gives me is: "Files from the internet may contain viruses. Enable Editing?"

Answer (score 8):

If CSV format is good for you, here is an example.

- **Ok...I just read a comment where you explicitly say it isn't good for you. My bad for not learning to read before coding.**

As far I know, Excel can handle CSV.

```js
function fnExcelReport() {
var i, j;
var csv = "";

var table = document.getElementById("table");

var table_headings = table.children[0].children[0].children;
var table_body_rows = table.children[1].children;

var heading;
var headingsArray = [];
for(i = 0; i < table_headings.length; i++) {
  heading = table_headings[i];
  headingsArray.push('"' + heading.innerHTML + '"');
}

csv += headingsArray.join(',') + ";\n";

var row;
var columns;
var column;
var columnsArray;
for(i = 0; i < table_body_rows.length; i++) {
  row = table_body_rows[i];
  columns = row.children;
  columnsArray = [];
  for(j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
      var column = columns[j];
      columnsArray.push('"' + column.innerHTML + '"');
  }
  csv += columnsArray.join(',') + ";\n";
}

  download("export.csv",csv);
}

//From: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18197511/2265487
function download(filename, text) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

    if (document.createEvent) {
        var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        event.initEvent('click', true, true);
        pom.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    else {
        pom.click();
    }
}
```

```html
<iframe id="txtArea1" style="display:none"></iframe>

Call this function on

<button id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport();">EXPORT
</button>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head1</th>
      <th>Head2</th>
      <th>Head3</th>
      <th>Head4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>44</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, It really help me. Can you anyone suggest how to get table headers as bold in csv file.

Comment: CSV files does not store style data so that's not possible. Probably you want the same data as a spread sheet (Microsoft Excel or Libre Office Calc), which could have said style. Assuming you are on Windows and you want a excel file, you could hack your way into using PowerShell module ImportExcel (https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) to (1) read the CSV (2) create an excel file with a table (this would have the whole table stylized, not only the header as bold), but doing this is not straightforward. Sorry, but I cannot help you further in that matter. Good luck if you want to try this.

Answer (score 3):

add this to your head:

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/>`

and add this as your javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
</script>
```

Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cmewv/537/

Comment: What should you do if you wish to specify the name of the imported Excel file? For instance, if you want your file to be named "example" when downloaded?

Comment: I implemented this solution and it works like charm! Thanks man.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
<table id="exportable">
<thead>
      <tr>
          //headers
      </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
         //rows
</tbody>
</table>
```

Script for this

```
var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
            type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
        });
saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **tableToExcel.js** to export table in excel file.

This works in a following way :

1). **Include this CDN in your project/file**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/linways/table-to-excel@v1.0.4/dist/tableToExcel.js"></script>
```

2). **Either Using JavaScript:**

```
<button id="btnExport" onclick="exportReportToExcel(this)">EXPORT REPORT</button>

function exportReportToExcel() {
  let table = document.getElementsByTagName("table"); // you can use document.getElementById('tableId') as well by providing id to the table tag
  TableToExcel.convert(table[0], { // html code may contain multiple tables so here we are refering to 1st table tag
    name: `export.xls`, // fileName you could use any name
    sheet: {
      name: 'Sheet 1' // sheetName
    }
  });
}
```

3). **Or by Using Jquery**

```
<button id="btnExport">EXPORT REPORT</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnExport").click(function() {
        let table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
        TableToExcel.convert(table[0], { // html code may contain multiple tables so here we are refering to 1st table tag
           name: `export.xls`, // fileName you could use any name
           sheet: {
              name: 'Sheet 1' // sheetName
           }
        });
    });
});
```

You may refer to this github link for any other information

https://github.com/linways/table-to-excel/tree/master

or for referring the live example visit the following link

https://codepen.io/rohithb/pen/YdjVbb

This will download the export.xls file

Hope this will help someone :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<hrml>
  <head>
     <script language="javascript">
      function exportF() {
  //Format your table with form data
  document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text").value;
   document.getElementById("input1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text1").value;
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var html = table.outerHTML;

  var url = 'data:application/vnd.C:\\Users\WB-02\desktop\Book1.xlsx,' + escape(html); // Set your html table into url 
  var link = document.getElementById("downloadLink");
  link.setAttribute("href", url);
  link.setAttribute("download", "export.xls"); // Choose the file name
  link.click(); // Download your excel file   
  return false;
}
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<form onsubmit="return exportF()">
  <input id="text" type="text" />
  <input id="text1" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<table id="table" style="display: none">
  <tr>
    <td id="input">
    <td id="input1">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a style="display: none" id="downloadLink"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

İf you have a too much column , try to use this code. You can split easily.

```html
function iterate( tab,  startIndex , rowCount){

    var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
    var textRange; var j=0;
    J=startIndex;

    for(j = startIndex ; j < rowCount ; j++) 
    {   
 
        tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
        //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,""); // remove if u want images in your table
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
    {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus(); 
        sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
    }  
    else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text)); 
  
  
} 
 
function fnExcelReport()
{
    var indirilecekSayi = 250;
  
    var toplamSatirSayisi = 0;

    var baslangicSAyisi = 0;

    var sonsatirsayisi = 0;
   
    tab = document.getElementById('myTable'); // id of table
    var maxRowCount = tab.rows.length;
    toplamSatirSayisi = maxRowCount;

  
  
    sonsatirsayisi=indirilecekSayi;
    
  
    
    var kalan = toplamSatirSayisi % indirilecekSayi;

    var KalansızToplamSatir=ToplamSatirSayisi-kalan;
    var kacKati=Tsh / indirilecekSayi;



 alert(maxRowCount);
    alert(kacKati);


    for (let index = 0; index <= kacKati; index++) {
        
        if (index==kacKati) {
           
            baslangicSAyisi =sonsatirsayisi;
           
            sonsatirsayisi=sonsatirsayisi+kalan;
           
            iterate(tab, baslangicSAyisi, sonsatirsayisi);
      
        }else{

           
           
            iterate(tab , baslangicSAyisi , sonsatirsayisi);
          
            baslangicSAyisi=sonsatirsayisi;
           
            
            sonsatirsayisi=sonsatirsayisi+indirilecekSayi;
            if(sonsatirsayisi>ToplamSatirSayisi){
                sonsatirsayisi=baslangicSAyisi;
            }

        }
            

    }

}
```