# File format or File extension not valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I am using [**rainabba/jquery-table2excel**](https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel) to export html table to excel .On clicking the button the file gets download but excels reports either the file or format is corrupted.Please suggest.

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-table2excel-master/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#myButton").click(function (e){
        $(".mytable").table2excel({
            name:"new File",
            filename:"work",
            //fileext:".xlsx"

        });

    });

    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="myButton">Click To Download</button>
    <table class="mytable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>new1</th>
            <th>new2</th>
            <th>new3</th>
            <th>new4</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377796/export-html-table-to-excel-doesnt-open-in-office-2010/38379929#38379929

Comment: done still the same issue @AxelRichter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="tableToExcel(\'#divId\', \'Excel Report\')">Generate Excel</Button>
<div id="divId">
    <table class="mytable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>new1</th>
            <th>new2</th>
            <th>new3</th>
            <th>new4</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

    var tableToExcel = (function () {
                var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
                    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
                    , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
                    , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
                return function (table, name) {
                    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                    var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
                    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
                }
            })()
```

use this code..for generate excel file..

Comment: @SunUser Please give more details about your code.. or add fiddle

Comment: @user6390636 - Still I'm getting the message in excel when opening the file - "The file format and extension of filename don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe." Please help...