# Table Header is not showing in exported PDF/EXCEL if I am using column search option in dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, datatables

I am a new user to dataTables.
I am exporting PDF/EXCEL by using buttons. Here facing one issue.
if I am using column search option then header columns are not visible in PDF/EXCEL.
Can u please help me. Thanks in advance.

here is my code:

```
$('#exampleList thead tr#filterrow th').each( function (exampleListId) {
var title = $('#exampleList thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();

$(this).html( '<input type="text" style="width: 90%;"  id="exmpl'+exampleListId+'" placeholder="Search '+title+'"/>' ).focusout(function (e) {
    window.flagfocus=true; 
    window.searchColDets.push({
    "column": e.target.id,
    "value": e.target.value
    });             
  });       
});

$('#exampleList').DataTable({
    data: partyListArr,
    "order": [[ 2, "asc" ]],
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "stateSave": true,
    "scrollY":   410,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "lengthMenu" : [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    "Filter": true,
    "destroy" : true,
    "deferRender": true,

    "sDom":'T<"toolbar">Blrtip',      
    buttons: [

            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                text: 'Save current page',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                pageSize: 'LEGAL',                  
                exportOptions: {                        
                    modifier: {
                        page: 'current'
                    },
                    columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10 ],                         
                },                 
            },
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10 ]
                }
            },             
        ]
 }); //Close datatable
```

Comment: Please show how you export the PDF, i.e the dataTable initialisation code.

Comment: check this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38802239/6390636

Comment: hi @davidkonrad, here i have added dataTable initialisation code. Now can you please help.

Comment: @neerajsimon, there is nothing wrong with your code, it works right away except you forget to set a proper fileextension to the xlsx downlooad -> https://jsfiddle.net/zm825k01/6/

Comment: hi @davidkonrad, with this initialisation, code is working fine but i have added column search in header as required(above code), with that code, in PDF/EXCEL, header is not showing. Without column filter its working superb. But as per my requirement i cant give column search in footer. It has to be display on header only.

Answer (score -1):

Add Code

```
<span class="hidden">' + title + '</span> 

$(this).html(
    '<span class="hidden">' + title + '</span>
    <input type="text" style="width: 90%;" id="exmpl'+exampleListId+'" placeholder="Search '+title+'"/>' 
).focusout(function (e) {
    window.flagfocus=true; 
    window.searchColDets.push({
        "column": e.target.id,
        "value": e.target.value
    });             
});
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because it can be difficult for the original poster (or future readers) to understand the logic behind them. Please, edit your answer and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from it. Thanks!