# Not able to open Export HTML table to excel in Microsoft excel viewer.

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, export

I am having problem in opening Excel file that I downloaded from doing the Excel export of the HTML table from Javascript. Its does not  get open in Microsoft excel viewer or Microsoft Office 2016 but the same file can be open from the office 365. Does not any body have any idea how to fix this problem. Microsoft also said there may be some problem in opening Excel workbooks after MS16-088 version is installed.

Comment: Probably this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377796/export-html-table-to-excel-doesnt-open-in-office-2010

Comment: In Microsoft Excel viewer we don't have the access to change the trust settings.